# how to save high quality image to phone gallery by camera intent

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-gallery, android-camera-intent

I am trying to develop app which save image to gallery.
I want to call the camera through intent, capture images, and save it locally in the gallery
but the issue is image quality is very poor. can anyone help me figure out why?

```
if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
           
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                someActivityResultLauncher.launch(cameraIntent);}
 

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
        if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK) {
            bitmap = (Bitmap) Objects.requireNonNull(result.getData()).getExtras().get("data");
        }
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);     
        saveimage(bitmap);
     }
```

```
private void saveimage(Bitmap bitmap){
     Uri images;
     ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q){
         images = MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY);
     }else {
         images = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
     }
     ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
     contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, System.currentTimeMillis() +".jpg");
     contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "images/*");
     Uri uri = contentResolver.insert(images, contentValues);
     try {
         OutputStream outputStream = contentResolver.openOutputStream(Objects.requireNonNull(uri));
         bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
         Objects.requireNonNull(outputStream);

        //

     }catch (Exception e){
        //
         e.printStackTrace();

     }
 }
```

Comment: bitmap = (Bitmap) Objects.requireNonNull(result.getData()).getExtras().get("data");
this line gives you thumnail. That's why image quality is not good.

Comment: Refer this link for saving high quality images https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics#TaskPath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
if you get image from data directly, it's in bad quality

Answer (score 0):

Your code is the legacy equivalent of [using `ActivityResultContracts.TakePicturePreview`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts.TakePicturePreview). It is specifically set up to return a low-resolution bitmap, suitable for a preview.

Instead, [use `ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture), and supply your destination `Uri` as part of the contract.

See [this](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/mobile-development/tutorials/536924/android-native-take-a-picture-with-activityresult-api) and [this](https://medium.com/codex/how-to-implement-the-activity-result-api-takepicture-contract-with-uri-return-type-7c93881f5b0f) for more.